# Google Directions API transit returns always "ZERO_RESULTS"

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api, travel-time

i'm developing an app that use google API to obtain a transport solution to reach a location at a desired time.

My code that call google API work perfectly with "driving" and "walking" travel mode, but with "transit" and "bicycling" the response is always marked with the status "ZERO_RESULTS" and no routes is calculated.
This, by the google documentation, means that transit and bicycling are not available in the country where the solution must be calculated.
I tried with several country and I always had the same result, I tried also with the Google example (for transit) in the overview and it doesn't work.

The parameters that I pass with the HTTPS request are: origin, destination, travel mode, arrival_time.
The first thing that I tried is to change arrival_time, in case the value is referred to the past or to a too distant future, but it doesn't work.

In case I don't pass "arrival_time" the response is perfect, but I don't understand because in the Google Documentation is clear that arrival_time is a possible argument of the https request also with the transit travel mode. Without this argument the request is useless for my goal.

The curious thing is that if i pass "transit" (with arrival or departure time) the response is this:

```
{
   "available_travel_modes" : [ "DRIVING", "WALKING" ],
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJu46S-ZZhLxMROG5lkwZ3D7k",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ53USP0nBhkcRjQ50xhPN_zw",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

And if I pass "bicycling" (with all the other parameters unchanged):

```
{
   "available_travel_modes" : [ "DRIVING", "WALKING", "TRANSIT" ],
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJu46S-ZZhLxMROG5lkwZ3D7k",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ53USP0nBhkcRjQ50xhPN_zw",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

So in the second case the API said that TRANSIT is available and this doesn't make sense at all!

The format of the location that I use is geographical coordinates to avoid cases of ambiguity.

Hope that I give enough information to make you able to help me.

EDIT: sorry, i was thinking that my post was clear enough.
I use Google Directions API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

My problem is with "transit" and "bicycling" as travel mode and is not a code problem, but the problem appears at the level of https response, even with the google example for "transit" that can be found on the overview i obtain a "ZERO_RESULTS" response.
This is the URL of the example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=75+9th+Ave+New+York,+NY&destination=MetLife+Stadium+1+MetLife+Stadium+Dr+East+Rutherford,+NJ+07073&mode=transit&arrival_time=1391374800&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

And here is the two URL that get me the two response that I copied above:
with transit:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Rome&destination=Milan&mode=transit&arrival_time=1513162800000&key=++API_KEY++
```

and with bicycling:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Rome&destination=Milan&mode=transit&arrival_time=1513162800000&key=++API_KEY++
```

in the code I use for origin and destination geographical coordinates as here:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.9027835,12.496365500000024&destination=45.4642035,9.189981999999986&mode=transit&arrival_time=1513162800000&key=++API_KEY++
```

the only difference is that google do not recognize geocoded waypoints:

```
{
   "available_travel_modes" : [ "DRIVING", "WALKING" ],
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [ {}, {} ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

If I use "driving" as travel mode this worked:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.9027835,12.496365500000024&destination=45.4642035,9.189981999999986&mode=driving&arrival_time=1513162800000&key=++API_KEY++

{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "EjJQaWF6emEgZGVsbGEgUmVwdWJibGljYSwgMTAsIDAwMTg1IFJvbWEgUk0sIEl0YWxpYQ",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJC5u9LazGhkcRXAZQFNDTpKc",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 45.4731019,
               "lng" : 12.6177051
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 41.9028523,
               "lng" : 9.1839517
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Dati mappa ©2017 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "573 km",
                  "value" : 572600
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 ore 51 min",
                  "value" : 21069
               },
               "end_address" : "Via Silvio Pellico, 2, 20121 Milano MI, Italia",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 45.46495119999999,
                  "lng" : 9.1892874
               },
               "start_address" : "Piazza della Repubblica, 10, 00185 Roma RM, Italia",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 41.9028523,
                  "lng" : 12.4964704
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "93 m",
                        "value" : 93
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 19
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 41.9035781,
                        "lng" : 12.4959908
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Procedi in direzione \u003cb\u003enord\u003c/b\u003e da \u003cb\u003ePiazza della Repubblica\u003c/b\u003e verso \u003cb\u003eVia Giuseppe Romita\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "ycw~F}ugkAU?I@E@E@a@RG@EDED_@d@OP"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 41.9028523,
                        "lng" : 12.4964704
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  // cut
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "52 m",
                        "value" : 52
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 14
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 45.4665738,
                        "lng" : 9.1889772
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continua su \u003cb\u003eVia Santa Margherita\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "ogotGoxaw@`@`@j@h@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 45.4669622,
                        "lng" : 9.189359399999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,2 km",
                        "value" : 192
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 87
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 45.46495119999999,
                        "lng" : 9.1892874
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Svolta a \u003cb\u003esinistra\u003c/b\u003e e prendi \u003cb\u003eVia Silvio Pellico\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "aeotGcvaw@Xw@DCBAxC@~A?d@A"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 45.4665738,
                        "lng" : 9.1889772
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "//collapsed//"
         },
         "summary" : "A1/E35 e A1",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

and if I use "transit" without an arrival time it works:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.9027835,12.496365500000024&destination=45.4642035,9.
189981999999986&mode=transit&key=++API_KEY++
```

and:

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "EjJQaWF6emEgZGVsbGEgUmVwdWJibGljYSwgMTAsIDAwMTg1IFJvbWEgUk0sIEl0YWxpYQ",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRYxePKzGhkcRsgPwamn2Pfo",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 45.4969308,
               "lng" : 12.5528041
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 41.892252,
               "lng" : 9.188611
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Dati mappa ©2017 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "arrival_time" : {
                  "text" : "13:55",
                  "time_zone" : "Europe/Rome",
                  "value" : 1513169733
               },
               "departure_time" : {
                  "text" : "10:10",
                  "time_zone" : "Europe/Rome",
                  "value" : 1513156231
               },
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "571 km",
                  "value" : 571467
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 ore 45 min",
                  "value" : 13502
               },
               "end_address" : "Piazza del Duomo, 1, 20121 Milano MI, Italia",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 45.4639037,
                  "lng" : 9.188611
               },
               "start_address" : "Piazza della Repubblica, 10, 00185 Roma RM, Italia",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 41.9028429,
                  "lng" : 12.4964793
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,1 km",
                        "value" : 102
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 87
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 41.902193,
                        "lng" : 12.4958041
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Cammina fino a Repubblica",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "wcw~F_vgkA@CBADABA@A@?B?D?B?B@B?B@BBB@@BBBDH@D@H@@?D?BDRBL?@DXBLBJDHBFVM"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 41.9028429,
                        "lng" : 12.4964793
                     },
                     "steps" : [
                        {
                           "distance" : {
                              "text" : "54 m",
                              "value" : 54
                           },
                           "duration" : {
                              "text" : "1 min",
                              "value" : 49
                           },
                           "end_location" : {
                              "lat" : 41.9024775,
                              "lng" : 12.4962611
                           },
                           "html_instructions" : "Procedi in direzione \u003cb\u003esudest\u003c/b\u003e verso \u003cb\u003ePiazza della Repubblica\u003c/b\u003e",
                           "polyline" : {
                              "points" : "wcw~F_vgkA@CBADABA@A@?B?D?B?B@B?B@BBB@@BBBDH@D@H@@?D?B"
                           },
                           "start_location" : {
                              "lat" : 41.9028429,
                              "lng" : 12.4964793
                           },
                           "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                        },
                        {
                           "distance" : {
                              "text" : "48 m",
                              "value" : 48
                           },
                           "duration" : {
                              "text" : "1 min",
                              "value" : 38
                           },
                           "end_location" : {
                              "lat" : 41.902193,
                              "lng" : 12.4958041
                           },
                           "html_instructions" : "Esci dalla rotonda e prendi \u003cb\u003ePiazza della Repubblica\u003c/b\u003e",
                           "polyline" : {
                              "points" : "oaw~FstgkADRBL?@DXBLBJDHBFVM"
                           },
                           "start_location" : {
                              "lat" : 41.9024775,
                              "lng" : 12.4962611
                           },
                           "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                        }
                     ],
                     "travel_mode" : "WALKING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,4 km",
                        "value" : 437
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 46
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 41.9011732,
                        "lng" : 12.4996019
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Metropolitana verso Anagnina",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "u_w~FwqgkAeBIBoA@I|ByM~CmELR"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 41.902193,
                        "lng" : 12.4958041
                     },
                     "transit_details" : {
                        "arrival_stop" : {
                           "location" : {
                              "lat" : 41.9011732,
                              "lng" : 12.4996019
                           },
                           "name" : "Termini"
                        },
                        "arrival_time" : {
                           "text" : "10:12",
                           "time_zone" : "Europe/Rome",
                           "value" : 1513156353
                        },
                        "departure_stop" : {
                           "location" : {
                              "lat" : 41.902193,
                              "lng" : 12.4958041
                           },
                           "name" : "Repubblica"
                        },
                        "departure_time" : {
                           "text" : "10:11",
                           "time_zone" : "Europe/Rome",
                           "value" : 1513156307
                        },
                        "headsign" : "Anagnina",
                        "line" : {
                           "agencies" : [
                              {
                                 "name" : "Atac",
                                 "phone" : "011 39 06 57003",
                                 "url" : "http://www.atac.roma.it/"
                              }
                           ],
                           "color" : "#e27439",
                           "name" : "Metro A",
                           "short_name" : "MEA",
                           "url" : "http://muovi.roma.it/percorso/js?query=MEA&cl=1",
                           "vehicle" : {
                              "icon" : "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/subway2.png",
                              "local_icon" : "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/it-metro.png",
                              "name" : "Metropolitana",
                              "type" : "SUBWAY"
                           }
                        },
                        "num_stops" : 1
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "TRANSIT"
                  },

                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "2,6 km",
                        "value" : 2641
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "6 min",
                        "value" : 330
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 45.4639037,
                        "lng" : 9.188611
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Metropolitana verso San Donato",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "//collapsed//"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 45.4844397,
                        "lng" : 9.202612799999999
                     },
                     "transit_details" : {
                        "arrival_stop" : {
                           "location" : {
                              "lat" : 45.4639037,
                              "lng" : 9.188611
                           },
                           "name" : "Duomo"
                        },
                        "arrival_time" : {
                           "text" : "13:55",
                           "time_zone" : "Europe/Rome",
                           "value" : 1513169730
                        },
                        "departure_stop" : {
                           "location" : {
                              "lat" : 45.4844397,
                              "lng" : 9.202612799999999
                           },
                           "name" : "Centrale FS"
                        },
                        "departure_time" : {
                           "text" : "13:50",
                           "time_zone" : "Europe/Rome",
                           "value" : 1513169400
                        },
                        "headsign" : "San Donato",
                        "line" : {
                           "agencies" : [
                              {
                                 "name" : "COMUNE DI MILANO",
                                 "phone" : "011 39 02 0202",
                                 "url" : "http://www.muoversi.milano.it/"
                              }
                           ],
                           "color" : "#ffea00",
                           "name" : "M3 - Linea Gialla",
                           "short_name" : "3",
                           "vehicle" : {
                              "icon" : "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/subway2.png",
                              "local_icon" : "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/it-metro.png",
                              "name" : "Metropolitana",
                              "type" : "SUBWAY"
                           }
                        },
                        "num_stops" : 4
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "TRANSIT"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "//collapsed//"
         },
         "summary" : "",
         "warnings" : [
            "Le indicazioni per tragitti a piedi sono in versione beta. Presta attenzione – questo percorso potrebbe non disporre di marciapiede o aree pedonali."
         ],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits your issue.  If I use the place Ids in the responses above in a Google Maps Javascript API Directions Service request, it seems to work (gives me a TRANSIT response, with an arrival time and a departure time).

Comment: I edited my post, hope this will be more clear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in your request is the value that you pass as an `arrival_time` parameter. Please note that this value must be in seconds:

> **arrival_time** — Specifies the desired time of arrival for transit directions, **in seconds** since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. You can specify either departure_time or arrival_time, but not both. Note that arrival_time must be specified as an integer.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests

You are passing milliseconds `1513162800000` that corresponds to `03/22/49920 @ 8:00am (UTC)`, the correct value is `1513162800` that corresponds to `12/13/2017 @ 11:00am (UTC)`.

The request should be:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.9027835%2C12.496365500000024&destination=45.4642035%2C9.189981999999986&mode=transit&arrival_time=1513162800&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The same request in Directions calculator:

https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=41.9027835%2C12.496365500000024&destination=45.4642035%2C9.189981999999986&mode=transit&arrival_time=1513162800

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You, i was wondering that something with the time format was not correct, but the fact that driving and walking were working have misguided me.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone else, I also found that setting a `departure_time` too far in the future (more than a year in my case) led to a "ZERO_RESULTS" response.  Making it closer to the present fixed this.